# How to access an AWS RDS host in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have setup my first AWS VPC.  It has a public subnet, and two private subnets.  One of the privates has an RDS instance, and the other is vacant (in a different AZ).  I followed the tutorials on AWS to set up the routing and VPC Security Groups.  I don't have NAT server for the private subnets.

My question is, how do I go about accessing the RDS instance in the private subnet using the MySql client?  I set up rules in the Web Server Security Group that allows outbound access on 3306, and the Database Security Group allows inbound access on the same port.

When I SSH into the server on the public subnet and run `mysql -h hostname -p` I get an error message about an unknown host name.  I tried the full RDS endpoint name as the host name.  I also tried just the host-name portion of the name.  Am I going about this the right way?  Does the MySql client use the 3306 port?  Or do I have to open another port?

Comment: You certainly sound like you're going about things the right way in general.  Unknown host name speaks to DNS issues, not anything firewall related.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  I need to specify the port number when making the connection, per this article:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html